# How to draw text in front of the background?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a program in pygame. The program first typewrites some text according to a event in the event loop. The problem with this is that the text will be behind the background.

The section that typewrites stuff:

```py
        elif event.type == write_text_0_event:
            if index_0 <= len(msg0) - 1:
                current_text_0 += msg0[index_0]

                text = font.render(current_text_0, True, (255, 255, 255))
                screen.blit(text, (100, 100))

                index_0 += 1
```

The part that draws the background:

```py
while running:
    # [...] (the event loop)
    screen.blit(city_bg, (0, 0))
```

I have tried butting the `screen.blit()` line in front of the event loop but still, the text is behind the background.

How can I make the text appear in front of the background instead of it appearing behind the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw the text permanently, you need to draw it in the application loop. When you draw the text in the event loop, it will only be drawn in the frame in which the event occurs.
Define the variable `text` before the loop (`text = None`). Set the variable in the event loop. And draw the `text` in the application loop if `text != None`:

```py
text = None

# application loop 
while running:
    # [...]

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
 
        elif event.type == write_text_0_event:
            if index_0 <= len(msg0) - 1:
                current_text_0 += msg0[index_0]
                text = font.render(current_text_0, True, (255, 255, 255))
                index_0 += 1

    screen.blit(city_bg, (0, 0))
    if text != None:
        screen.blit(text, (100, 100))

    # [...]
```